# Shutdown logs out instead of shutting down

Tags: 10.10, login, shutdown, restart

Many times (not all the time) when I want to shutdown or restart, the computer does not shutdown but goes to the  screen for changing the user.  I am the only user of my computer.  So I had to shutdown a second time.  Is there a solution for this?

Comment: It sounds like when you click the shutdown button it is issuing the log off command instead of the full shutdown command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When Shutting down or hibernating it just goes to the login screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93883/when-shutting-down-or-hibernating-it-just-goes-to-the-login-screen). Furthermore, this user isn't likely to ever accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue reported as a bug for 10.04 and 10.10. Supposedly it has been fixed for those versions. Guess it was a problem with ConsoleKit.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/consolekit/+bug/554158

However, there appears to be either a regression or entirely new cause of this infernal behaviour in the 11.xx series. I inconsistently experience this problem on 11.10. See this associated bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792

Answer (score 0):

Go to System > Preference > Power Management and choose from there.  I very seldom shut down, only if my computer is running slowly or there is a hardware problem.  In Ubuntu I suspend the computer and spin down the drives, and when I'm ready to go, it only takes 10 seconds to spin up and go. Yeah! I love this system!

Answer (score -1):

In the terminal you can enter:

Shutdown: `sudo halt`

Restart: `sudo reboot`

To bring up the terminal quickly you can press `Ctrl Alt t`.

Comment: this is not very practical.  First your must go to the terminal, then type the command an then you  give your password for a sudo.

Comment: For some reason, I've never been asked for a password with these two.

Comment: @Julien: They've served me well. I'm not a power user by far and shutting down my PC takes me no more than 3 seconds of work. Faster than clicking on Shutdown.

Comment: It sounds like when you click the shutdown button it is issuing the log off command instead of the full shutdown command.

Comment: @mschulze you say it wright.  I am not agree for doing it via the terminal.  I set a extra shutdown button on the panel, and the pull down menu of this button is different.  The computer shutdown after 60 seconds.  Nevertheless this is not the best way to do. Other solutions?