# When Shutting down or hibernating it just goes to the login screen

Tags: login, shutdown, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t shut down nor reboot without console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71506/i-cant-shut-down-nor-reboot-without-console)

Title says all. When I choose shut down or hibernate if my computer has been on a while, it just goes to the log-in screen. If I choose the shut down option there, it does nothing.

It only happens if I leave it on for a while. I do not have auto login enabled. I am running 11.10 ( with all the latest updates). I can shut down using the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Answer (score 3):

Used to have the same problem, run this on a terminal:

```
sudo poweroff
```

The problem get fixed by itself after several times i had to do that.

Also check if theres a .Xauthority file in your home folder owned by root.
Log in a text console (Alt+Ctrl+F1) at the login screen, and then run

```
sudo rm ~/.Xauthority
```

Hope it helps. (:

Comment: Thanks! I will see if this works. Also, is it safe to do the terminal command even if you do not see that file, and do you mean do the sudo power off command when I have the problem, or run it several times in a row.

Comment: **1.** Yes it is Safe, if the file doesn't exists, it will show you a message like "the file doesn't exist" or something like that. 
**2.** I mean do the `sudo poweroff` command when you have the problem only once (It will be enough)

Comment: it didn't work for me, the file exists, but removing it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem. Here is the associated bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792