# When I click Shutdown, computer logs out instead of shutting down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, bug-reporting, restart, logout

I have a problem somewhat similar to the one in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42032/shutdown-logs-out-instead-of-shutting-down) question..

I am on Ubuntu  16.04 LTS and I usually install system updates when they are available. Yesterday I noticed that when I click on **shutdown**, the computer shows **Logout and Lock** dialog just before **loging out AUTOMATICALLY instead of shutting down**. I have to run shutdown command on the terminal to really shut down my computer. The above link did not help me. Hope you can understand me and solve my problem.

Comment: How about this command : `qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Shutdown
` Does it log you out or shutdown ?  This is supposed to be the same call that gets executed from the session indicator

Comment: I've been having this same issue since last update, maybe it's some sort of new bug.  I know that "me too" comments are not welcome here, but by knowing that this is affecting many people we should feel encouraged to file a bug report.  The question is... wich package is producing this?

Comment: @Serg I get this  -------- Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod No such interface 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' on object at path /com/canonical/Unity/Session

Comment: Finally I found the solution, this is a bug and see it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cairo-dock-core/+bug/1242112). I have installed Plank and that was the interrupter, and when I delayed the start of it problem fixed. I did not put this as an answer because I found answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451791/problems-with-shutdown-and-logout-after-upgrading-to-14-04),[here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/621732/shutdown-button-only-logs-out-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: I still don't know why this happened :(

Comment: I had a similar problem after manually installing [retropie]((https://retropie.org.uk/)) on 16.04. There was nothing of importance on the system so I just reinstalled and updated to 16.04.5. I'm not into gaming enough to dig deeper into this.